# How to fix error while installing Laravel first time?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I use a `WAMP` server located at drive E: and I try to install `Laravel` for the first time.

First I installed `Composer` and then I installed `Laravel`. Then I ran my server located at `http://localhost/laravel/public/`, but it gave this error:

```
Warning: require(E:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  241656  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0003  244568  require( 'E:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php' ) ..\index.php:22

( ! ) Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'E:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0002  241656  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0003  244568  require( 'E:\wamp\www\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php' ) ..\index.php:22
```

How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install project dependencies via composer. Inside the project folder run:

```
composer install
```

---

If you have no composer installed, here's how:

- Linux: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx
- Windows: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Comment: So I open cmd and run its ?

Comment: RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29:

Comment: this is another error, you need to make another question with detailed description.

Comment: has now it work for me bro I just folow u , and past 'cipher' => 'AES-128-CBC', it to in my config app thz bro